# LocalBroadcastManager didn't receive messages

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My LocalBroadcastManager callback function dosen' receive messeges. Can someone tell my why?

I try to do it on my Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (4.1.2 -Jelly Bean, API 16).

**SenderClass:**

```
public static final String BROADCAST = "com.android.SOME_BROADCAST";
private Context context;

public SenderClass(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //...

    Intent intent = new Intent(BROADCAST);
    //intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SOMEEXTRA, "some extra");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
    //just to keep it simple i do it here
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive"); //this is never called!

        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume()");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
                broadcastReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(SenderClass.BROADCAST)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause()");

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
```

edit: here the manifest

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android....">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".Services.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post the android manifest?

Comment: may be a dumb question, are you receiving the events when MainActivity is visible?

Comment: How do you send broadcast? From where your `SenderClass` is called?

Comment: MyService got an instance of SenderClass.

Comment: Is your `MainActivity` visible ??? when you send the broadcast ??

Comment: how can i check this?

Comment: Ah, yes of course. The MainActivity is visable.

Comment: Also all the other things are working my SenderClass did...just the broadcast back to my activity doesn't work

Comment: `context` in senderclass could be null..!!

Comment: No its not...i use the context also for other stuff in this class and it works fine.

Comment: Try passing Activity object instead of context..!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this step:-
Register your broadcast in onCreate and Unregister broadcast in onDestroy of Activity.

Thanks,
It may helpful for you.

Comment: Check your sender class calling it properly or not